# How do I insert data into MYSQL via FORM

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have spent the last 2 days trying to create a form to enter data into an SQL database.  The database is functional, the tables are made and I can enter data via MYSQL. I'm using 2 files, `bidinput.html` and `bidentry.php`

Bidinput.HTML:

```
    <html>
    <body>
    <form action="bidentry.php" method="post">
    Bidder: <input type="text" name="BidderNumber"><br>
    Description: <input type="text" name="Description"><br>
    Price: <input type="decimal" name="Price"><br>
    Quantity: <input type="integer" name="Quantity"><br>
    Lot: <input type="text" name="Lot"><br>
    <input type ="submit">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

bidentry.php:

```
 <?php
    ######### From bidinput.html

    $BidderNumber = $_POST['BidderNumber'];
    $Description = $_POST['Description'];
    $Price = $_POST['Price'];
    $Quantity = $_POST['Quantity'];
    $Lot = $_POST['Lot'];
    ########

    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "abcd1234";
    $dbname = "auction";
    // Create connection

    $mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

    // Check connection
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . $mysqli->connect_error;
    }
    else{
        echo "Connected successfully";

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Bids (BidderNumber,Description,Price,Quantity,Lot) VALUES         ('$BidderNumber','$Description','$Price','$Quantity','$Lot')";

    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $mysqli->error;

    }$mysqli->close();

    ?>
```

When I run click the submit button I get the following error:

> Connected successfullyError: INSERT INTO Bids (BidderNumber,Description,Price,Quantity,Lot) VALUES ('202','candy','3','1','')

Comment: You don't get an error. You output the query without ever executing it. You should use prepared statement.

Answer (score 1):

**WARNING** You need to protect yourself from SQL injection. You should be using prepared statements to shield yourself from SQL injection.

You are not actually running any queries with your current code.

You need to use [mysqli query](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php):

```php
$mysqli->query($sql);
```

**Prepared Statement Example**

Here is an example of an INSERT with prepared statements based on your code:

```php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO Bids (BidderNumber, Description, Price, Quantity, Lot) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssss", $_POST['BidderNumber'], $_POST['Description'], $_POST['Price'], $_POST['Quantity'], $_POST['Lot']);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
```

Edit: Put this at the top of your PHP file:

```php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

You don't want to display errors in production but in a dev environment it's ok.
You might want to check your PHP.INI file. At the very least `log_errors` should be on by default and errors would be logged in your apache error log.

Comment: I still get a white screen, apache2 log shows no errors. is there some kind of debug script that I can run?

Comment: Does it the data get into the table?

Comment: It's working now.  I rebooted the SQL server and suddenly it is working.  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: So let's see if I understand this correctly.  The prepared statement basically has 4 parts ....  1. Prepare. this is where I define the columns where I want to insert data. 2. Bind using $POST[ ] this identifies the data to be entered into the columns identified by the prepare line.  3. Execute and 4. Close. Without the Close line would I still be susceptible to sql injection?

Comment: Obviously I'm using an old reference PHP & MYSQL for Dummies 3rd edition. It makes no reference to prepared statements.  Is there a reference that you would recommend?

Comment: I would suggest either going to PDO or some database abstraction layer like Nette Database. Moving to a DBAL makes life a bit easier. Currently I'm using Laravel which has an ORM called Eloquent.